# Does Keyboard.Modifiers reflect the "real" current state or the state according to keyboard events?

Tags: .net, keyboard

Does [`Keyboard.Modifiers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.modifiers.aspx) reflect the "real" current state of the keyboard or is it based on keyboard messages in the window message queue?

MSDN says:

> Gets the set of ModifierKeys that are currently pressed.

Does this mean *physically* pressed?

Comment: No.  It uses GetKeyState(), not GetAsyncKeyState()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it means the keys that are *physically* pressed.